# Launcher and some icons do not appear

Tags: graphics, launcher, icons

This is the first time I use Linux (Ubuntu - 13.10 )
After installation, there is no Launcher bar and some icons, like minimize / maximize and close, are missing in any window. What I've realized is that my graphics card is unknown;
it's an onboard card, and my motherboard is: GA-8I865GME-775-RH.

I've tried some solutions already but don't work.
Thanks

Comment: Did you try [Xorg-edgers PPA repository](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa)?

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by graphics card is unknown. where did you check it? did you apply any incomplete custom theme?

the generic answer would be that search in dash for details. and tell me what you see in graphics. then go to software and updates and look at the tab additional drivers. your graphics card must be shown there. install it.

there is a second alternative. i have an old nvidia graphics card on my pc at home and gnome or gnome based environments(unity which you are using, cinnamon) don't work properly on that. so i use linux mint mate edition. you may try that.

Comment: 1- all setting (tab)- detailes(icon) - overview : here the cpu - os - memory are shown correctly but there is "unknown" in front of Graphics 2- no additional drivres available at the additional tab in software and updates

Comment: 1- all setting - detailes - overview : the CPU -OS - Memory are shown correctly but the information  in front of Graphics is "unknown"

Comment: i guess you have to do a research about what graphics card you are using. this is tough. so, i propose that you ditch ubuntu and download linux mint mate edition (both of them are linux but different flavours). linux mint mate edition supports more drivers. you can persist on ubuntu and try to configure what is wrong but changing to linux mint mate edition is simpler.

Comment: lshw command shows the graphics is 82865G Integrated graphics controller by Intel  - do you think Linux mint is suitable for electronic engineers or amateur programmers?